# SSL Mutual Authentication from React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm trying to perform SSL Mutual Authentication from React Native, with a library like `axios` or `fetch`.
Basically, I need to present a certificate with each call, a reverse proxy is already configured to recognize this certificate and let the request pass-through.

I managed to make my code work in NodeJS with following syntax :

```
const fs = require('fs');
const https = require('https');
const axios = require('axios');

const httpsAgent = new https.Agent({
  cert: fs.readFileSync('./assets/mycert.pem'),
  key: fs.readFileSync('./assets/mykey.pem')
});

axios.get('https://myurl.com', { httpsAgent }).then((data) => {
   console.log(data);
}).catch((error) => {
   console.log(error);
});
```

I tried to get this code work in React Native with following libraries :

- Node libs for React Native (for `https`): https://github.com/parshap/node-libs-react-native
- File access to replace `fs` : https://github.com/joltup/rn-fetch-blob

It seems that it does not work because of `https.Agent`. When I try to log content of httpsAgent described above from React Native, I get `{}`.

Would you have an idea ? Thanks !

Comment: Is this for a mobile app? Or desktop/browser? You cannot use 'https' module on mobile.

Comment: for mobile. how to perform mutual tls if https is not available on mobile ?